# Rust Winapi is printing garbage while printing unicode international characters

Tags: winapi, rust, print-spooler-api

I have been dabbling with [winapi](https://crates.io/crates/winapi) crate for printing international characters. For some reason the thermal printer seems to be printing garbage.

I have tried to encode using utf8 encoding of data but with no luck.

Has anyone been able to print international charset using winapi on a thermal printer?

Here is the 3 step code snippet of what I have tried:

```
Step 1: Open Printer
--------------------

    let printer_name = "MY_PRINTER_NAME";

    let mut printer_name_wide: Vec<u16> = printer_name.encode_utf16().chain(std::iter::once(0)).collect();
    let mut printer_handle: winapi::um::winnt::HANDLE = std::ptr::null_mut();
    let datatype: &str = "RAW"; // XPS_PASS, EMF, 
    let datatype_wide: Vec<u16> = datatype.encode_utf16().chain(std::iter::once(0)).collect();                      

    let mut defaults = PRINTER_DEFAULTSW  {
        pDataType: datatype_wide.as_ptr() as *mut u16,
        pDevMode: ptr::null_mut(),
        DesiredAccess: 0x40000000, //GENERIC_WRITE
    };    

    let result = unsafe {
        OpenPrinter2W(
            printer_name_wide.as_mut_ptr(),
            &mut printer_handle,
            &mut defaults,
            std::ptr::null_mut(),
        )
    };


Step 2: Start Doc Printer
-------------------------
            let job_name = "PrintJob";
            let utf16_job_name: Vec<u16> = job_name.encode_utf16().collect();     

            let datatype: &str = "RAW"; // XPS_PASS, EMF, 
            let mut datatype_utf16: Vec<u16> = datatype.encode_utf16().chain(std::iter::once(0)).collect();
            
            let docinfo1w = DOC_INFO_1W {
                pDocName: utf16_job_name.as_ptr() as *mut u16,
                pOutputFile: ptr::null_mut(),
                pDatatype: datatype_utf16.as_mut_ptr(), // This works
            };

    fn struct_to_bytes<T>(data: &T) -> Vec<u8> {
        unsafe {
            let size = std::mem::size_of::<T>();
            let ptr = data as *const T as *const u8;
            std::slice::from_raw_parts(ptr, size).to_vec()
        }
    }    

    let struct_bytes: Vec<u8> = struct_to_bytes(&docinfo1w);   

            let result = StartDocPrinterW (
                printer_handle,
                1, // Number of copies
                struct_bytes.as_ptr() as *mut u8);
                println!("Failed to start page. Error code: {}", unsafe {
                    winapi::um::errhandlingapi::GetLastError()
                });


Step 3: Print using WritePrinter
--------------------------------

            let page_result = unsafe { StartPagePrinter(printer_handle) };

    println!("Page started successfully!");
                let text_to_print = "Zażółć gęślą jaźń";
                let utf16_text: Vec<u16> = text_to_print.encode_utf16().chain(std::iter::once(0)).collect();       

                let mut bytes_written: u32 = 0;

                let write_result = unsafe {
                    WritePrinter(
                        printer_handle,                      
                        utf16_text.as_ptr() as *mut winapi::ctypes::c_void,
                        utf16_text.len().try_into().unwrap(),
                        &mut bytes_written,
                    )
                };
```

**Points to Highlight:**

- Used RAW as datatype
- As for as possible, have used unicode version of functions, that ends with W than A
- Encoded, data using encode_utf16

Comment: You are sending UTF-8 encoded text to the printer, but promise that it was UTF-16 encoded. Garbage is the expected outcome. You'll have to re-encode your `text_to_print` using [`encode_utf16`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.encode_utf16) for example.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have infact used the following as well but with no luck.
```
let text_to_print = "Hello, 你好, привет!";      
let utf16_text: Vec<u16> = text_to_print.encode_utf16().collect();
```

Comment: Is ASCII OK? What about other printers?

Comment: ASCII seems to be fine. I have tried with couple of other printers. 
However, if we rewrite using CreateDCW, DOCINFOW, ExtTextOutW functions, which essentially prints as document, it seem to be printing international characters. But this approach doesn't understand pos printer commands.